# Java liquibase variables in yaml

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I've got liquibase yaml file with few duplicating variables e.g.:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: insert_app_properties_account_service_dev
      author: author
      changes:
        - insert:
            tableName: properties
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: application
                  value: account-service
              - column:
                  name: profile
                  value: dev
              - column:
                  name: KEY
                  value: server.port
              - column:
                  name: value
                  value: 0
              - column:
                  name: label
                  value: master
```

values `dev, account-service and master` are always the same inside a single file. Is there any option to set them as variable and use like `{{ profile }}?`. I was trying to do something like: `profile: dev` and then use it as profile but then I'm getting parse exception.

Comment: can you try `${profile}`?

Comment: then it saves ${profile} to database without resolving the value